# android - imageView - set non-resource image programatically

Tags: android, layout, imageview, picasso

I need to develop this example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/golden_gate" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

        android:padding="12dip"

        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"

        android:text="Golden Gate" />

</FrameLayout>
```

but since the imageView is read from the Internet (thru Picasso), I'll need to set the image Resource programatically.
The  `android:src="@drawable/golden_gate"` is useless for me. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)

Comment: yes, I've seen `public void setImageResource (int resId)` many times, but in this case, how is it set? the Picasso function is:
`picasso.load(foto.getURL())
     .placeholder(R.raw.place_holder)
     .error(R.raw.big_problem)
     .resize(150, 150)
     .centerCrop()
     .into(imageView);`

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. What do you want to set programmatically? A bitmap? A drawable?

Comment: I want to display two images overlaid. the 1st one is retrieved with Picasso, the one on top of that is a drawable or a text

Answer (score 0):

picasso placeholder option should let you assign a placeholder image, which is displayed until the actual image is downloaded from the network

http://square.github.io/picasso/